# Flutter- How can I add Title to SliverList's SliverChildBuilderDelegate?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I want to achieve a design similar to the below image. I have used SliverList with CustomScrollView. Now, How can I add a title to the SliverList?

[image]

There are multiple horizontal and vertical scroll views therefore I am using CustomScrollView to optimize the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use SliverToBoxAdapter between SliverList:

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Text('Covid info'),
)
```

Comment: I had the same thought. But according to flutter documentation, using multiple SliverToBoxAdapter, are not more efficient. You can see [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverToBoxAdapter-class.html)

Comment: I think you misunderstood what that means, it means do not use "multiple SliverToBoxAdapter" as "SliverList".  it is fine to use it as title of SliverList

Comment: Got it. Thank you.